# How to catch the 404 error with cakephp 3 in a productive environment

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to catch all 404 errors (controller not found) in my new cake app. But I don't have a clue how.

Is there any configuration for that? Or must I catch the thrown error by myself? If so, where?

Comment: As you can see from the answers you are receiving, your question is very vague, "_catch all 404 errors_" could mean anything. Please be a little more specific as to what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, that could work. Define you own error handler, that extends default ErrorHandler

```php
<?php
// Custom Handler - goes in src/Error/AppError.php
namespace App\Error;

use Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException;
use Cake\Error\ErrorHandler;

class AppError extends ErrorHandler
{
    public function _displayException($exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof MissingControllerException) {
            // Here handle MissingControllerException by yourself
        } else {
            parent::_displayException($exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Then register this handler as default.

```php
// Register handler in config/bootstrap.php
use App\Error\AppError;

$errorHandler = new AppError();
$errorHandler->register();
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'App\Error\AppError' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fitness/config/bootstrap.php on line 58